# Will the turtle be alive when it reaches the planet?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

Suppose, the scientists found a planet 370 light-year away. They sent a 50-year-old turtle at a velocity of 0.7c to the planet. The average lifetime of a turtle is 450 years. [Light year = $9.46\times 10^{15}m$]. Now, will the turtle be alive when it reaches the planet?

My [book's(1)](https://scontent.fdac23-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/187509298_513435456518644_2491219774174329677_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=LvX5ZXrl5YgAX_hFQQO&_nc_ht=scontent.fdac23-1.fna&oh=38c97fe93c3baf5205f41f63795b34e7&oe=60CC1514) [solution(2)](https://scontent.fdac23-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/186544547_1885304444978633_2141225476762566015_n.jpg?_nc_cat=104&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=sUjQnhQE4c8AX_Zls7C&_nc_ht=scontent.fdac23-1.fna&oh=76a16f5b9791969b8b3df315ef6f7317&oe=60CE413F):

370 light year = $3.5\times10^{18}m$

The time taken by the turtle to travel 370 light-year will be measured from the perspective of the earth....(i)

$$t=\frac{s}{v}$$
$$\implies t=\frac{3.5\times 10^{18}}{0.7\times3\times10^{8}}$$
$$t=1.67\times10^{10}s=528.5y$$

Now,

$$t=\frac{t_o}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
$$t_o=377.42y$$

Now, the age of turtle as experienced by him=$(50+377.42)=427.42y$

Therefore, the turtle will be able to reach the planet alive.

Now, I take issue with the (i) assumption. How did the book know that the time was being measured from the perspective of the earth?

Comment: Because both $s$ and $v$ are measured in the Earth reference frame

Comment: Scientists have sent the tortoise. This means that they have send it from the earth. So it is good to guess from the given conditions that all the measurements are being made from the earth's frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book *asserted* that the time was being measured from the perspective of the Earth. You can always choose to measure time and distance in whatever frame is most convenient. But it is very important to clearly state what coordinates you are using, because times and distances are different in different reference frames. The book's answer simply says "when we use the Earth's measurements, this is what we get" and then uses that answer to find the result from the turtle's perspective. You could use other measurements, but given that the distances and speeds in the problem are given in relation to the Earth, that seems like the most straightforward coordinate system to start with.

Comment: According to @FrodCube, as both $s$ & $v$ are measured from the earth's frame of reference, therefore $t$ is also must be according to the reference frame of the earth. It is a concrete comment. What is your opinion regarding this?

Comment: If you use the Earth's $s$ and $v$ to calculate $t$, then clearly you get Earth's $t$, so yes, that's what I meant by saying that the calculation is easiest using Earth coordinates. You *could* use different $s$ and $v$ (e.g. the turtle's) to get the answer, but you'd have to derive them first.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you give me some pointers as to how I can calculate $s$ & $v$ from the perspective of the turtle? Won't $s$ be the same from both the perspective of the turtle and from that of the earth at the time of takeoff of the turtle? Won't $v$ be $0$ from the perspective of the turtle?

Comment: From the turtle's perspective the Earth and distant planet are moving past it at $-v$, and the distance between them is Lorentz contracted to $s \sqrt{ 1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}$

Comment: Just calculated it according to the turtle's frame of reference: the answers match! Thanks for your great help!

Comment: Note to self: watch professor dave explains- length contraction